d3 axis labels and ticks are invisible
I am trying to view the axis labels of my d3 timeline chart. We are using v3 of d3 at work which can't be easily changed (there are many charts written this way)
For some reason that I can't figure out for the life of me, the CSS of the text elements inside the SVG are not visible. The elements exist in HTML, and they can be selected using the inspector, but I cannot see the labels or the ticks.

My code is as follows:


var TIMELINE_METHODS = (function() {
    "use strict";

    var COLORS = ["green", "red", "blue", "orange", "indigo",
                  "fuchsia", "black", "cyan", "darkgreen", "pink"];

    var MARGINS = {
        top : 0,
        bottom : 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    };


    var TRANSLATE = function(x,y) {
        return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    };


    var createGraphRoot = function(rootNode, params) {
        d3.select(rootNode).selectAll("svg").remove();

        var margins = params.margins || MARGINS;

        var root = d3.select(rootNode)
                     .append("svg:svg")
                        .attr("width", params.width + margins.left
                                                    + margins.right)
                        .attr("height", params.height + margins.top
                                                      + margins.bottom)
                     .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", TRANSLATE(margins.left,
                                                     margins.top));

        return root;
    };

    var applyScales = function(root, xScale, yScale) {
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(d3.time.day, 1);
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

        /*var maxRange = function(scale) {
            // rangeExtent is more accurate for ordinal scales
            return d3.max((scale.rangeExtent || scale.range)());
        };
         */

        root.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", TRANSLATE(0, yScale.rangeExtent()[1]))
            .call(xAxis);

        root.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
    };

    var fillWithData = function(root, data, xScale, yScale, barColor) {
        root.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.start); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.name); })
            .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.end) - xScale(d.start); })
            .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("fill", barColor);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Exports


    var executionHistoryTimeline = function(rootNode, data, startDate, endDate) {
        // test with mock data
        data = [
            {name: "Task 1", start: new Date("2023-05-01"), end: new Date("2023-05-02")},
            {name: "Task 2", start: new Date("2023-05-02"), end: new Date("2023-05-03")},
            {name: "Task 3", start: new Date("2023-05-01"), end: new Date("2023-05-03")}
        ];
        startDate = new Date("2023-05-01");
        endDate = new Date("2023-05-03");

        var width= 800, height= 200;
        var root = createGraphRoot(rootNode, {width:width, height:height});

        var xScale = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate)])
            .range([0, width])

        var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.1);

        applyScales(root, xScale, yScale);
        fillWithData(root, data, xScale, yScale, 'steelblue');
    }

    return {
        "executionHistoryTimeline" : executionHistoryTimeline
    };

})();
/* Ensure SVG elements are visible */
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: black;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    visibility: visible;
}

.axis text {
    fill: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    visibility: visible;
}

text {
    fill: black;
}

rect {
    fill: #009900;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page" style="background:white;">
  <h1><b/>Job Execution History</h1>

  <p>View the past ___ days of history starting from ___</p>
  <p>
    <button id="toggle-timeline-view" class="btn btn-link clickable">Timeline view</button>|
    <button id="toggle-table-view" class="btn btn-link clickable">Table view</button>
  </p>

  <div id="timeline-view">
    Timeline view here
    <div id="date-picker">
      <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2024 - 01/31/2024" />
    </div>
    <div id="timeline"></div>
<!--    <svg id="timeline" width="800" height="200"></svg>-->
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#toggle-table-view').click(function () {
        $('#table-view').show();
        $('#timeline-view').hide();
      });
      $('#toggle-timeline-view').click(function () {
        $('#timeline-view').show();
        $('#table-view').hide();
      });
      
      var root = $('#timeline').get(0);
      TIMELINE_METHODS.executionHistoryTimeline(
          root,
          [{}],
          new Date('2024-05-01'),
          new Date('2024-05-30')
      );
    });
  </script>
</div>



What I have tried so far is manually updating the fill, stroke, color, fields both in CSS & in the inspector, all the way up the chain to the SVG, and still nothing. I've tried adding visibility tags to every element as well. I've tried adding the fill attributes directly to the axis creation like this post said: d3js v4 x-axis-label is there but not visible but this also had no visible changes.
Can anyone provide some assistance as to what might be going on here? I'm not even sure what to investigate next. I attribute d3 to voodoo magic at this point, and I've got some deliverables that I need to hit this sprint. I'd rather not try to bring in a new charting standard.
I'm happy to provide any other details necessary, but you should be able to reproduce based on the code I posted above.
Thank you in advance!

It’s helpful if you provide a runnable snippet of code. That said, the issue may be that there isn’t room in your SVG for the axes and ticks, so try a non-zero bottom margin.

By runnable snippet you just mean throw everything into a single html file or something?

No, there’s a “JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet” button that will let readers run your code in place right in the question.

@Noleli I have added a runnable code snippet. That's a cool feature. Didn't know it existed :D

The text is off the edge of the page. x="-9", if you fix that i.e. x="9" then the graph elements hide it because they are drawn on top.

It's definitely something to do with drawing outside of the boundaries. I've played around with the width and found that if I edit the width post-render, that the axes show up. I'll be trying both of your suggestions right now. Thank you!!!!
